# Why does JBoss 7.1.1 recognize localhost but not my IP address?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

Centos 6.5
JBoss 7.1.1.Final

starting jboss as ./standalone.sh

When I go to localhost:8080 there is jboss, nice and happy
When I go to 192.168.111.222:8080 I get a 404 page not found error

This is problematic.

I have looked at other questions here that have advocated the following

```
./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0
```

This gives an error. It says the address is already in use.

I have tried

```
./standalone.sh -b 192.168.111.222
```

This doesn't work either.Same error as above. I have checked each time to see if there is another jboss process running out there and the answer is no.

I have tried modifying the jboss/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml interfaces to accept all connections. That didn't work either

No matter what I do, it always says:

```
Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
```

and going to ipaddr:8080 doesn't work, but localhost:8080 does work.

I saw one thread recommend modifying your hosts file to point your ip address at local host: I already have an entry there pointing my ip address at a domain name (which also doesn't work)

Other services on my machine work just fine, able to reach addresses whether I use localhost or specify the IP address, so this seems to be a jboss specific problem.

How do I fix this? I haven't used jboss before and I'm starting to see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably some other process listening on port 8080. Try to find the process by

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 8080
```

You can simply change the AS7 port numbers by setting port-offset. Start JBoss AS7 like this:

```
./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=150
```

The web port will be 8230 in this case. (i.e. you'll use 192.168.111.222:8230 in the browser).